# how to call home button simulate from service?

Tags: android, emulation, android-homebutton, pressed

how can simulate home button in android from other app?
i create a app  use service to floating over other applications.

i need when home button in my app pressed other application goes to home screen like another assistive touche app like iphone.

please see image below i placed into phone app original and when i pressed home go to home page.
[image]

Comment: no body here i need that !

Comment: 2 days past and nothing here! please i need  this . ifound one way to go to home screen but not well.